# Routing access point internet through PC on same network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have just bought a Cisco wireless access point (Cisco Wireless-N Access Point WAP4410N). It is connected to the same network as my computer. My devices can connect to the access point and get internet access, but what I want to do is have their connection go through my computer. To do this I have set the gateway of the access point to my computers IP however this does not work. What do I need to do to set this up?

Comment: You don't want to set the AP's gateway, but the connected devices'. I assume they're getting their IP configuration via DHCP from some Internet gateway device...? If you really *need* to route your traffic this way, you'll probably want VLANs.

Comment: What do VLAN's have to do with it? VLAN's are a layer 2 construct, not a layer 3 construct. VLAN's don't provide routing capability but instead impose a need to implement inter-VLAN routing. I don't see how VLAN's are at all related to the problem or the solution.

Comment: Your computer need to be configured as a router and the devices need to be configured to use your computer as their Default Gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You need to set the gateway IP address on each of your wireless devices to point to your computer's IP. Assuming, of course, that your computer is set up to forward IP traffic.

Long answer: A wireless access point is not a router, but basically a network switch. Thus it operates on a lower level than a router and merely pipes through layer 2 network traffic. It does not know, or care about, IP addresses (other than for its configuration interface). In fact you could run non-IP protocols over it.